# How to stop Maven/Artifactory from keeping Snapshots with timestamps

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, artifactory

Due to disk space considerations I'd like to only ever keep one version of any snapshot in my repository. Rather than keeping multiple versions with timestamp suffixes

*e.g. ecommerce-2.3-20090806.145007-1.ear*

How can I set this up? Is this a build setting or repository (Artifactory) setting

Thanks!

Comment: You can find ans on following link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275466/how-do-you-deal-with-maven-3-timestamped-snapshots-efficiently/38600178#38600178](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275466/how-do-you-deal-with-maven-3-timestamped-snapshots-efficiently/38600178#38600178)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The simplest (and [recommended](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Usage)) way is to use non-unique snapshots. If you must use unique snapshots, you can do this in Artifactory by specifying the <maxUniqueSnapshots> property on the <localRepository> definition in artifactory.config.xml

For example:

```xml
<localRepository>
  <key>snapshots</key>
  <blackedOut>false</blackedOut>
  <handleReleases>false</handleReleases>
  <handleSnapshots>true</handleSnapshots>
  <maxUniqueSnapshots>1</maxUniqueSnapshots>
  <includesPattern>**/*</includesPattern>
  <snapshotVersionBehavior>non-unique</snapshotVersionBehavior>
</localRepository>
```

For reference you can do this in [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) (via the UI) by setting up a [scheduled service](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/config.html#config-sect-scheduled-services), it allows you to specify the minimum number to retain, the maximum period to retain them for, and whether to remove the snapshot if a release version is deployed.

Comment: Thanks Rich - Artifactory seems to also allow you to change these values through the gui - it's just not too well documented!

Comment: If you have a reference to any relevant docs, can you add it to your answer

Comment: using the non-unique snapshots is generally bad practice as it makes it very difficult to trace conflicts down to developer machines. You're much better off keeping the timestamps and using Nexus to clean up the old snapshots.

Comment: non-unique snapshots are no longer available in Maven 3: https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-NonuniqueSnapshotDeployments

Comment: You can do it from the Artifactory UI going to Admin > Repositories > edit "libs-snapshot-local" and in the dropdown named Maven Snapshot Version Behavior change it to "Deployer"

Comment: No you can not do this in Nexus, the minimum number to retain is about "snapshot component", not timestamped versions.

Answer (score 14):

**NOTE THAT THIS FEATURE/CAPABILITY HAS BEEN REMOVED IN MAVEN 3.0**

Just add something to my own question:

Adding

```
<distributionManagement>
    ...
    <snapshotRepository>
        ...
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </snapshotRepository>
    ...
</distributionManagement>
```

to my parent *pom* also contributed to the solution of this.

See:

http://i-proving.com/space/Jessamyn+Smith/blog/2008-06-16_1

To alter the unique settings on the repository in Artifactory - log in as an admin - and select edit on the relevant repo - screenshot here:

http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Understanding+Repositories

Comment: This behavior has changed in Maven 3. See: [Nonunique Snapshot Deployments](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-NonuniqueSnapshotDeployments)

Answer (score 4):

Artifactory can clean up old unique snapshots. However, we have found unique snapshots to be non-useful for the purpose of tracking down dependencies or rolling-back to a specific version. There are better alternatives for doing this, which are cleaner and more reliable. That is why Artifactory defaults to prefer non-unique snapshots, and this policy can be *centrally* controlled (which is unique to Artifactory).
You can read more about this, as well as the auto-cleanup feature [here](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Local+and+Remote+Repositories).

Answer (score 1):

Using non-unique snapshots is not a good way to go. Instead get a repository manager that can clean up snapshots and configure that to keep disk space down. Having the timestamped snapshots makes it much easier to track down issues since you can easily see which version actually is being used.

Answer (score 1):

```
<plugin>         
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>         
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>         
                    <version>1.7</version>         
                    <executions>           
                        <execution>             
                            <id>remove-old-artifacts</id>             
                            <phase>package</phase>             
                            <goals>               
                                <goal>remove-project-artifact</goal>             
                            </goals>            
                            <configuration>  
                                <removeAll>true</removeAll><!-- When true, remove all built artifacts including all versions. When false, remove all built artifacts of this project version -->             
                            </configuration>          
                        </execution>         
                    </executions>       
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Will NOT work in Maven 3 as it was quoted by Apache below

```
It's not recommended to use non-unique snapshots since they lead to non-reproducible builds. The main use case for these was to save disk space in the repository, but this is best handled by scheduling a periodic snapshot removal task to keep the number of versions down
```