# maven tomcat plugin keeps growing war when using snapshot version

Tags: maven-tomcat-plugin

the pom.xml excerpt below shows the structure of the project that leads
to ever an ever growing war file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
     ...
    </parent>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- ...-->
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>...</artifactId>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- tomcat deployment -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>...</url>
                    <server>...</server>
                    <path>...</path>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

the war contains as many jar files as the local maven repository has timestamped snapshot versions.

**How can this be reduced to just the current version?**

I have found a workaround in:

- [How do you deal with maven-3 timestamped snapshots efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275466/how-do-you-deal-with-maven-3-timestamped-snapshots-efficiently)

to use another maven plugin to remove superfluous timestamped snapshot version jars

And i have filed a bug report at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-268

Answer (score 0):

this problem was fixed by some vodoo. Very strange

Comment: In other words Off Topic->a problem that can no longer be reproduced ?

Comment: Yes - this seems to be the only known case. It really happened and I was able to make it go away. I don't know how any more.
Shall i file a deletion of the question or simply keep it unanswered incase somebody else has the same problem? - is there discussion on meta about such a case?

Comment: You might better investigate on Meta, I know the close reason from closing questions, I've not been in your situation yet. Regards.