# Using Maven install and deploy upload airtifact to nexus

Tags: java, maven-3, nexus

We need to upload artifacts to nexus with out including time stamp. We are using maven3 for compilation.

We have use `-DuniqueVersion=false` goal, but it is not working.

Is there any way to fulfil this requirement ?

Comment: You mean a snapshot version without time stamp, right? Anyway you should edit your question and add more information (e.g. parts of the pom) on what you already have.

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275466/how-do-you-deal-with-maven-3-timestamped-snapshots-efficiently

Comment: @Robert yes snapshot version without time stamp.