# Maven 3.3.1 - Disable timestamps

Tags: java, maven, timestamp, version, pom.xml

I have read that `<unique>` versions setting is no longer executed and is ignored in Maven 3 or later, as explained here: [Non-unique Versions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-Non-uniqueSnapshotDeployments). And by design, Maven 3 or later will always produce time stamped SNAPSHOT versions.

When I build artifacts though, I have some artifacts that only produce the base SNAPSHOT version, even if I build it multiple times, there .

After building some artifacts, in my local repository there will be that base artifact-SNAPSHOT file that I built, and a few other time stamped versions of the same artifact. There is the base artifact: artifactID-4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, and then there are others in the same directory with versions appended to them: e.g. artifact-4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-20160120.192041-37.jar.

I don't want the time stamp files built and put into my repository, as it only eats up disk space. I would like to figure out how to only produce the base 4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT version and nothing else.

Other than writing a script to deleted these accumulating time stamped artifacts, Has anyone figure out a way to disable them completely so they are not created in Maven 3 or later?

Comment: What do you means by timestamped artifacts ? The actifacts that are commited to your local repository ? The name of the file created after the build ?

Comment: There will be a timestamp for SNAPSHOT version only. Can you confirm that that's the difference?

Comment: Where do you find those artifacts with timestamps? Only in a repository manager like Nexus / Artifacts those kind of artifacts are being created and there exist a scheduled task in Nexus to cleanup the SNAPSHOT repository  on a regular basis...?

Comment: @Tunaki - Yes it is only for the SNAPSHOT version. Can I make it as so to overwrite the the 4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT each time, so that there will never be any timestamp versions created.

Comment: @JFPicard - Yes I am referring to the time stamped artifacts that are produced in the 4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT directory when you are building an artifact that already exist in your repository.

Comment: This question seams to be duplicated.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243574/how-to-stop-maven-artifactory-from-keeping-snapshots-with-timestamps

Answer (score 1):

With reference the another questionnaire page:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57951722/how-to-remove-timestamp-from-artifacts-uploaded-to-maven2-repository-on-nexus](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-deploy-plugin-2.6/examples/disabling-timestamps-suffix.html)

What you are asking to do is change the default behavior of Maven/Nexus. It keeps track of what is the "latest" based on the appended timestamp and sequential number. You only need specify "SNAPSHOT" and it will resolve the latest (caveat: local updates from remote are checked by default only @daily, unless -U specified. If you want to clear your remote (Nexus) repo, you can schedule a task to "Remove Snapshots from Repository". You can schedule that hourly or more (via Advanced / cron). It needs the timestamp and sequential # to know how far back to go to remove extra copies (by time or qty)

other wise give a try with **uniqueVersion=false**
[maven unique version artifact](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-deploy-plugin-2.6/examples/disabling-timestamps-suffix.html)

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:///C:/m2-repo \
                       -DrepositoryId=some.id \
                       -Dfile=your-artifact-1.0.jar \
                       -DpomFile=your-pom.xml \
                       -DuniqueVersion=false
```