# How to remove timestamp from artifacts uploaded to maven2 repository on nexus?

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I am uploading a few artifacts through a Jenkins pipeline on a Nexus repository, the repository is maven2 hosted. I use the following block in Jenkins to upload artifacts:

```
nexusArtifactUploader (
            artifacts: [
                    [artifactId: 'artifact-part1',
                    classifier: '',
                    file: "build/libs/artifact-part1.jar",
                    type: 'jar'],
                    [artifactId: 'artifact-part2',
                    classifier: '',
                    file: "build/libs/artifact-part2.jar",
                    type: 'jar']
                ],
                credentialsId: 'nexus_cred',
                groupId: "$group", nexusUrl: "$nexusUrl:8082",
                nexusVersion: 'nexus3',
                protocol: 'http',
                repository: 'project_dev',
                version: "$version-SNAPSHOT"
        )
```

It gets uploaded to nexus but the file name has a suffix of timestamp. I am not mentioning the timestamp anywhere, I am not sure how it gets added. This is how it looks:

[image]

I don't wan't the timestamp to be added. Adding the timestamp creates multiple versions, I would like to know if there is any way of removing the timestamp so that only one version is saved. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Snapshot artifacts are automatically stored with a timestamp inside the repository. You can still reference them by `0.1-SNAPSHOT` and Nexus will automatically resolve that.

So don't worry.

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded the snapshot by specifying `0.1-SNAPSHOT`, but is there any way to remove the timestamp if I want only one version to be present? It would be of great help if you could also tell me why the timestamp is added in the first place,

Comment: What you are asking to do is change the default behavior of Maven/Nexus. It keeps track of what is the "latest" based on the appended timestamp and sequential number. You only need specify "SNAPSHOT" and it will resolve the latest (caveat: local updates from remote are checked by default only @daily, unless -U specified. If you want to clear your remote (Nexus) repo, you can schedule a task to "Remove Snapshots from Repository". You can schedule that hourly or more (via Advanced / cron). It needs the timestamp and sequential # to know how far back to go to remove extra copies (by time or qty)

Comment: See [What is an Artifact Repository](https://blog.sonatype.com/2009/04/what-is-a-repository) for some more info. You could [Disable timestamps suffix in an artifact](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-deploy-plugin-2.6/examples/disabling-timestamps-suffix.html) but why worry about it? W/O timestamp it may not know if an uploaded artifact is newer than a locally cached copy or other issues may arise.

Comment: Okay, I understood it better after reading that article. Thank You.

Comment: You can also configure nexus how many SNAPSHOT artifacts to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to answer by JF Meier. I later found out that adding timestamps to SNAPSHOTS is the intended functionality. 
You can read more about it here : [What is an Artifact Repository?](https://blog.sonatype.com/2009/04/what-is-a-repository/)

Credits to [Ian W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598141/ian-w)